# How to open a whole Rails app in Notepad++

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows

I'm using Notepad++ on a Windows machine. On my Mac, I can open the whole Rails app in the text editor and then just click on files in the editor. however, in windows notepad++ it seems to require me to open each file individually.

Alternatively, is there a command I can use from the command line?

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856285/can-notepad-open-up-a-file-and-folder-browse-panel

Comment: thanks, strange that it's only a plugin feature

Comment: If you are stuck on a windows machine you might try the redcar editor. It requires Java, but I have it one a couple of Windows machines and it's pretty good.

Comment: As a side note, give Sublime a try. IMHO it's much better than Notepadd++. http://www.sublimetext.com/2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to create a project and add your source files.

1. You can go to Notepad++ "View -> Project -> Project Panel 1" (for example)
2. In the panel Right Click the Workspace Icon, Select "Add New Project"
3. Once the project is created right click it and select "Add Files From Directory".

It's not a top gun feature, but it surely makes the job.

Comment: Note: Im using Notepadd++ 5.9.6.2